# How to call a method from user control to aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to call a method from user control to aspx page

I'm trying but I am not able to call that method in aspx page

Code:

AddVisaUserControl.ascx.cs

```
public event EventHandler UserControlButtonClicked;

    public void OnUserControlButtonClick()
    {
        if (UserControlButtonClicked != null)
        {
            UserControlButtonClicked(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnUserControlButtonClick();
    }
```

.aspx

**Edit**

In the below code when the page load I am getting "null reference error"

```
AddVisaControl av; 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        av.UserControlButtonClicked  += new
                EventHandler(AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked);
    } 

  private void AddVisaControl_UserControlButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = (AddVisaControl)LoadControl(@"AddVisaControl.ascx");
        //ctrl.ID = i;
        this.rpt1.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks ok to me, is it just not firing? Whats the header for AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked?

Comment: Have you actually added the control to the aspx file? You can't just declare it like that. For one, it won't be initialized, hence the null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an uninitialized field:

```
AddVisaControl av;
```

whose default value is null, hence the NullReferenceException.

If you have added an instance of the UserControl to your aspx page, you should have an instance whose name is equal to the ID of the UserControl instance:

=== in Page.aspx

```
<uc1:AddVisaUserControl ID="MyControl" ... />
```

=== in Page.aspx.cs

```
MyControl.UserControlButtonClicked += ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response then how to call that event(UserButtonClicked)

Answer (score 1):

Your ascx control

```
public delegate void ButtonClickEventHandler(string data);
public event ButtonClickEventHandler ButtonClickEvent = null;

if (ButtonClickEvent != null)
            ButtonClickEvent("Send to aspx");
```

Your aspx page :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="uc1" 
             Src="~/Controls/AddVisaUserControl.ascx" %>
<uc:AddVisaControl id="uc1" runat="server" />


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uc1.ButtonClickEvent += new yourusercontrol.ButtonClickEventHandler(Login1_ButtonClickEvent);
    }

    void uc1_ButtonClickEvent(string data)
    {
        lbldefaultaspx.Text = data.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the delegate via the `+= new` syntax, but you do not have the actual method that gets invoked in your page code.

In other words, you need a `AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked` method in your .aspx page code, like this:

```
protected void AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked(object sender, 
                                                           EventArgs e)
{
    // Logic here for what the page does when the user control's remove 
    // button is clicked

}
```

UPDATE:

Upon the OP posting more code, it seems the user control is a null reference, because of this line:

```
AddVisaControl av;
```

This does not instantiate the user control, so you can do two things:

1. Instantiate the user control, like this:

   ```
   AddVisaControl av = new AddVisaControl();
   ```

   Invoke the delegate, like this:

   ```
   av.UserControlButtonClicked  += new
           EventHandler(AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked);
   ```
2. Add the user control to the markup of your page, like this:

   ```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="AddVisaControl" 
                Src="~/Controls/AddVisaUserControl.ascx" %>
   <uc:AddVisaControl id="AddVisaControl1" runat="server" />
   ```

   Invoke the delegate, like this:

   ```
   AddVisaControl1.UserControlButtonClicked  += new
           EventHandler(AddVisaUserControl_UserControlButtonClicked);
   ```

Comment: Option (1) above (instantiate the user control) doesn't make much sense: there's no point in instantiating a user control unless you add it to the control tree.

Comment: @Joe - I agree, just saying technically it would alleviate the null reference issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usercontrol.ascx

```
Me.Page.GetType.InvokeMember("ClosePopUp", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, Me.Page, New Object() {parameter1,parameter2})
```

ParentPage.aspx

```
Public Sub ClosePopUp(parameter1,parameter2)
/*Your Logic Here
End Sub
```